# Anaconda how to import keras-rl

Tags: python, keras, anaconda, spyder, reinforcement-learning

Sorry if this is a 'nooby' question, but I really don't know how to solve it. I've installed keras and a lot of other stuff for deep learning with Ananconda, but now I want to try to make something with Reinforcement Learning. So I've read that I need to install keras-rl, and I installed it as follows:

```
git clone https://github.com/matthiasplappert/keras-rl.git
cd keras-rl
python setup.py install
```

I have also installed gym:

```
pip install gym
```

But when I write in Anaconda Spyder 4 (4.1.2):

```
from rl.agents.dqn import DQNAgent
from rl.policy import EpsGreedyQPolicy
from rl.memory import SequentialMemory
```

... it says that ' ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rl' '. What's wrong? Thanks in advance for any answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try installing it from the Conda command line, probably the environments don't match for Anaconda to realize that rl is a library

Comment: Thanks, it solved that error, but now: 
  `File "D:\Python\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\keras_rl-0.4.2-py3.7.egg\rl\callbacks.py", line 9, in <module>
    import wandb

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wandb'` I get this error from `from rl.agents.dqn import DQNAgent`

Comment: The other lines: `from rl.policy import EpsGreedyQPolicy` and

`from rl.memory import SequentialMemory` they work just fine.

Comment: Have you tried doing the same conda installation procedure for wandb?

Comment: Yes, and it says: `PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels`. I wrote `conda install wandb`. Trying with pip now.